# Ubuntu terminal remove or upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Хочу установить Ubuntu 18.04 или 20.04 lts

Сейчас версия:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=19.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=disco
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.04"
```

При выполнении

> ```
> sudo do-release-upgrade -d
> ```

получаю если promt=lts

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> There is no development version of an LTS available.
> To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release
> set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.

Как можно вернуться на 18.04.3 lts? Подскажите пожалуйста! Использую terminal ubuntu

Comment: Не мудрить и просто переустановить систему с нуля не вариант?

Comment: подскажите, как это сделать через терминал, я в интернете не нашел ни одного гайда

Comment: *подскажите, как это сделать через терминал, я в интернете не нашел ни одного гайда* — для этого нужна возможность подключить блочное устройство (для загрузки с него) и доступ к консоли (монитор+клаваиатура), физический или эмулируемый. инструкциями по установке полны эти ваши интернеты, как королевские горшки поутру.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> вернуться на 18.04

вот этого без переустановки системы добиться нереально.

в вашем случае можно обновиться до (**следующей**) версии 20.04 (кодовое имя `focal`).

в общем и целом алгоритм обновления (до **следующей** версии) дистрибутива, основанного на *debian gnu/linux*, на первый взгляд довольно прост:

1. создайте резервные копии всей важной информации.
2. отключите в файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list` и `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` все неофициальные (для дистрибутива) репозитории.
3. замените в `/etc/apt/sources.list` упоминания имени текущей версии дистрибутива на имя новой (в вашем случае `disco` на `focal`).
4. обновите список пакетов:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. обновите сами пакеты (в данном случае это будет «минимально возможное обновление»):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
6. обновите пакеты более кардинально — уже с учётом перехода на новую версию дистрибутива:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

---

на docker-овском образе (с супер-минимумом установленных пакетов) всё проходит гладко:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti ubuntu:19.04 bash -c 'sed -i s/disco/focal/g /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && cat /etc/*release*'
...
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

на реальной системе (со многими тысячами установленных пакетов, да ещё и, как принято в ubuntu, из множества «левых» репозиториев) могут возникнуть проблемы. предусмотреть их все, естественно, невозможно. решать придётся в процессе, по мере возникновения.

Comment: `да ещё и, как принято в ubuntu, из множества «левых» репозиториев` — XD

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, ну не от хорошей же жизни придумали ppa и вот это всё. пакетов в дистрибутиве мало, вот пользователям и приходится пользоваться левыми репозиториями.

Comment: А если автор проги держит свою ппа со своей прогой - это тоже левая репа?

Comment: @donRumata, для дистрибутива — да.